# Webhook Command Discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I made an Webhook Command for my Discord Bot. It works great without any error but I was wondering if it was possible to show the username and avatar of the user in the webhook. Like if I use the command instead of showing the webhook name and avatar it shows my name and avatar or the person who uses the commands name and avatar. Here is my code:

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
  if (message.content.toLocaleLowerCase().startsWith("+hook")) {
    let webhookMsg = message.content.substring(9);
    webhookClient.send(webhookMsg)
  } 
})
```

Can you help me out? Thanks In Advance!

Comment: You can get those things from the webhook by accessing its properties like: `webhookClient.name`. You can read more about it here: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Webhook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add options in the second argument of the WebHookClient.send method, see example:

```js
    webhookClient.send('hello', {
        username: message.author.username,
        avatarURL: message.author.avatarURL()
    });
```